# Flexbox: why does content stretch columns if other columns cannot shrink?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have three columns in the container.
I want the columns to have equal width at all times — if content inside any column is to wide for it to preserve equal width, it should apply overflow, but never stretch.

If I use flexbox, the behavior is very weird. For `flex: 1 0 auto` wide content stretches the column (which should not be possible since other columns are not allowed to shrink).

Here is an example image for `1 0 auto` (orange is the wide content block and blue/green/gray are columns):
[image: flex-box]

Why does this happen (and why does the orange box have empty space at the right)?
Is that the expected behavior?

Note that I just found a workaround (setting width to `0`), so I am not interested in a solution — just in understanding of the situation.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j7web/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">    
  <div class="x1"></div>    
  <div class="x2"></div>
  <div class="x3">
      <div class="wide"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.container > * {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.wide {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #ff9900;
}

.x1 { background: #3498db; }
.x2 { background: #2ecc71; }
.x3 { background: #c0c0c0; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at how much empty horizontal space would exist in `.container` if all the `x#` had no width, you'll see that there's 300px (600px total minus 300px taken up by `.wide`). Since each of the children have `flex-grow: 1`, they will share equally in that space — that is, each will add 100px to its existing width. So, `x3` becomes 400px wide (300px for its contents, plus the 100px it got from the flexbox calculation). `flex: 1 0 0` fixes this because each item is considered to have 0 width for the initial space calculation, leaving 600px available which the three items share equally.

Answer (score 0):

[Is this what you're trying to achieve?](http://jsfiddle.net/j7web/3/)

```
.container > * {
    flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I noted that I can do that, but why does this happen? Shouldn't shrink=0 disallow shrinking of the containers? Or is it the side effect of auto-width calculation that happens before the flex applies? But then why disallowing growth gives a totally different result?